# My Numbers Spreadsheet does not show any data

Tags: mac, macbook, iwork, iwork-numbers

My Numbers spreadsheet shows blank even though it has data in it.

What could be wrong?

Please see attached image.
[image]

Comment: Can you open other files successfully, or is the trouble specific to this one file?

Comment: What happens when you zoom in from the 25% zoom you're currently at? Can you view some data using Quicklook?

Comment: Problem is with all files. I have tried changing the zoom level from 100% to 25% and reverse but it still does not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was seeing this spreadsheet in a virtual Mac. And for the processor which I had, it did not support rendering Number sheet properly. I checked it on a real Mac and it was working fine.

Hope this helps someone having similar problem.